# My if statement keeps returning 'None' for empty list

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement

I'm a beginner at coding in Python and I've been practising with exercises CodeWars.

There's this exercise which basically wants you to recreate the display function of the "likes" on Facebook, i.e. how it shows the number likes you have on a post etc.

Here is my code:

```
def likes(names):
    for name in names:
        if len(names) == 0:
           return 'no one likes this'
        elif len(names) == 1:
           return '%s likes this' % (name)
        elif len(names) == 2:
           return '%s and %s like this' % (names[0], names[1])
        elif len(names) == 3:
           return '%s, %s and %s like this' % (names[0], names[1], names[2])
        elif len(names) >= 4:
           return '%s, %s and %s others like this' % (names[0], names[1], len(names) - 2)

print likes([])
print likes(['Peter'])
print likes(['Alex', 'Jacob', 'Mark', 'Max'])
```

This prints out:

```
None
Peter likes this
Alex, Jacob and 2 others like this
```

My main issue here is that my first 'if' statement is not producing the string 'no one likes this' for when the argument: [] is empty. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: It is returning `None` because all functions that do not return anything explicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Just remove the line with `for` and that's it

Comment: Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 7):

If `names` is an empty list the `for` loop won't be executed at all, which will cause the function to return `None`. You should change the structure of your function (hint: you might not even need a loop, not an explicit one at least). There is no point in having a loop and then `return` on the very first iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it strictly correct to say "the `for` loop  won't be executed at all"? For example, if you put an `else` clause on this loop, the statements after the clause will be executed

Answer (score 4):

The for loop that you have done occurs one time for each element of the list, but you do non have elements in the list, so the loop won't occour, and the return value will be "None"

```
def likes(names):
    #for name in names:  #LOOK HERE: you definetly not need this loop
    if len(names) == 0:
       return 'no one likes this'
    elif len(names) == 1:
       return '%s likes this' % (names[0])
    elif len(names) == 2:
       return '%s and %s like this' % (names[0], names[1])
    elif len(names) == 3:
       return '%s, %s and %s like this' % (names[0], names[1], names[2])
    elif len(names) >= 4:
       return '%s, %s and %s others like this' % (names[0], names[1], len(names) - 2)
```

Comment: On Line 6: `return '%s likes this' % (names[0])`. else returns error. The edit is too small to make on your anwser